# How to loop main class

Tags: java, loops, program-entry-point

I am trying to make my rock paper scissors app loop if the user wants it to and am not sure how.
I am in a programming class but I broke my code while trying to fix it last time and managed to return to what I had before.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playAgain = "Y";

    while (playAgain.equals("Y") || playAgain.equals("y"))
        {
        String playerChoice = "";
        while (!playerChoice.equals("R") && !playerChoice.equals("P") && !playerChoice.equals("S"))
            {
            System.out.println("Please enter a correct character\n (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors.");
            playerChoice = scan.next();

         //Player choice to upper case to minimize the number of wrong inputs//
            playerChoice = playerChoice.toUpperCase();
            }

        int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        String compChoice = "";
        switch (randNum)
            {
            case 0:
                compChoice = "R";
                break;
            case 1:
                compChoice = "P";
                break;
            case 2:
                compChoice = "S";
                break;
            }
        System.out.println("The computer chose: " + compChoice);

        if (playerChoice.equals(compChoice))
            {
            System.out.println("It's a Tie!");
            } else if (playerChoice.equals("R") && compChoice.equals("S") || playerChoice.equals("P") && compChoice.equals("R") || playerChoice.equals("S") && compChoice.equals("P"))
            {
            System.out.println("You Win!");
            } else
            {
            System.out.println("You Lose");
            }
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again?\n(Y or N)");
        playAgain = scan.nextLine();
        if (playAgain.equals("N"))
            {
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide a bit more info than this please Brendan eg
What was the issue you found?
Is this the code that broke or the code that worked?
What is the difference between the two versions?

Comment: this looks like homework. please read [asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6619250) and [edit] your question if required.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you need agreement between your scan method calls.

Either both should be nextLine or both should be next.

As an aside - I quite like the use of .equalsIgnoreCase instead of .equals on string comparisons, since it makes the code simple and easy to read.  (You can skip the toUpperCase for instance, and the extra conditions)

---

As for why/what exactly the scanner is doing which causes that problem, that's a lot more detailed and fiddly.